# How to Optionally include .Includes()... a .IncludeIf(...) if you will?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am creation a repo class to for my EF entities. I have a primary entity, lets call it `Person`. Person of course has collections `Addresses`, `Cars`, `Pets`, `Loved Ones`, and `Secrets`

When I use `repo.GetPerson(id)` I would like to include some sort of flag to indicate if the query should .Include() any of the collections.Something like `[Flags] public enum AlsoInclude {Nothing=0, Addresses=1,Cars=2,Pets=4,LovedOnes=8,Secrets=16};` So GetPerson becomes `Person GetPerson(Guid id, AlsoInclude alsoInclude)`

Normally I would use `people.Include(p=>p.Addresses).Include(p=>p.Cars)/*...*/;`

I believe if I want to conditionally include the various collections, I would have to write 2^5 if tests for all the combinations.

Does something like `IncludeIf(...)` exists? Something where I could express

```
Person GetPerson(Guid id, AlsoInclude alsoInclude 
  => people.IncludeIf(alsoInclude.HasFlag(AlsoInclude.Addresses),p=>p.Addresses)
    .IncludeIf(alsoInclude.HasFlag(AlsoInclude.Cars),p=>p.Cars) /*...*/
    .Single(p=>p.Key==id);
```

Thanks in Advance.
-Df5

Comment: You don't need "2^5 if tests", you need just 5. Order of includes should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very easily do optional includes by composing the query conditionally, somewhat like this:

```cs
Person GetPerson(Guid id, AlsoInclude alsoInclude)
{
    var query = people;
    if (alsoInclude.HasFlag(AlsoInclude.Addresses))
        query = query.Include(p => p.Addresses);
    if (alsoInclude.HasFlag(AlsoInclude.Cars))
        query = query.Include(p => p.Cars)
    /*Any other conditional clauses go here*/
    return query.Single(p => p.Key == id);
}
```

You can then create an extension method that does this automatically to achieve exactly your theoretical `IncludeIf` operator.